# How to initialise an anonymous union within a struct in c

Tags: c, initialization, unions

I want to initialise all three arrays of mainstr , can anyone help me to initialise this anonymous union inside the struture? 0th index should initialise with interger array and 1st and 2nd indexes with char pointer.

```
typedef struct
{
   int testy;
   union
   {
      int a[3];
      char* b[3];
   }
   bool testz;
} testStr;


typedef struct
{
    testStr x[3];
} mainStr;
```

something like this,

```
mainStr test = {
                  {20, {{10, 20, 30}}, FALSE},
                  {10, {{"test1", "test2", NULL}}, TRUE},
                  {30, {{"test3", "test4", NULL}}, FALSE},
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [designators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization):

```
mainStr test = {{
                {20, {{10, 20, 30}}, false},
                {10, {.b={"test1", "test2", NULL}}, true},
                {30, {.b={"test3", "test4", NULL}}, false},
               }};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xsaKKPcas)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of work, but do-able.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
int foo() {
  typedef struct {
    int testy;
    union {
      int a[3];
      char *b[3];
    };
    bool testz;
  } testStr;

  typedef struct {
    testStr x[3];
  } mainStr;

  testStr test1 = {20, { {10, 20, 30}}, false};
  (void) test1;

  mainStr test = { //
      { //
          {20, { {10, 20, 30}}, false}, //
          {10, { .b={"test1", "test2", NULL}}, true}, //
          {30, { .b={"test3", "test4", NULL}}, false} //
          }//
      };
  (void) test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- `union { ... };` must end with semicolon.
- Use standard `bool` not some home-made version.
- `mainStr` Means there's a need for an extra pair of initializers, one for the struct, one for the array member `x`.

With those issues fixed, you can use designated initializers to tell the compiler which union member you are initializing:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
  int testy;
  union {
    int a[3];
    char* b[3];
  };
  bool testz;
} testStr;

typedef struct {
  testStr x[3];
} mainStr;

int main (void) {
  mainStr test = 
  {
    {
      {20, .a = {10, 20, 30}, false},
      {10, .b = {"test1", "test2", 0}, true},
      {30, .b = {"test3", "test4", 0}, false},
    }
  };
}
```

It might be a good idea to use designated initializers for *all* struct/union members though, to get self-documenting code.